# How to decrease MySQL container memory usage?

Tags: mysql, docker, memory

**Problem:**

MySQL is taking over 350MB on idle, as shown in `docker stats`

**Tried:**

Tweaking the configuration file as suggested in posts [like this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64055/how-to-reduce-mysql-memory-used).

---

**Added these lines to the file:**  /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=64M
innodb_log_buffer_size=256K
max_connections=5
key_buffer_size=8
thread_cache_size=0
host_cache_size=0
innodb_ft_cache_size=1600000
innodb_ft_total_cache_size=32000000
thread_stack=131072
sort_buffer_size=32K
read_buffer_size=8200
read_rnd_buffer_size=8200
max_heap_table_size=16K
tmp_table_size=1K
bulk_insert_buffer_size=0
join_buffer_size=128
net_buffer_length=1K
innodb_sort_buffer_size=64K
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mysql
COPY my.cnf /etc/mysql/
```

---

**Actual:**

I made sure `my.cnf` changes were in the container, however its still taking over 350MB idle, is it possible to get it below that or am I trying something just not possible?

Comment: This is more of a database admin question for [the DBA site](https://dba.stackexchange.com). MySQL isn't necessarily intended to run in really memory-constrained environments. Is this a problem for you, or just something you want to tune? Normally the more memory MySQL has, the faster it can operate.

Comment: @tadman that sounds like a good idea, will do so tomorrow, its not really a problem, was just a question that came to my mind but its bothersome to not know the answer

Comment: It's 2020. Even a $35 computer like a Raspberry Pi has 1GB of memory, so keeping it super lean isn't really a priority. If you do need a lean solution, consider [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/index.html) which has no server component.

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @Jouo Let me know when the data requested Mar 7, 2020 has been posted to allow 'server workload tuning analysis', please.  Comment with atsign leading my name will send a message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prepared repository:
https://github.com/alexanderkoller/low-memory-mysql

Before using this repository's configurations memory is about 458Mib/s
After: 31.12Mib/s

Tested on mysql 5.6

Comment: [**Please do not upload images of text (code/input/output/errors, or otherwise) on Stack Overflow**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please [edit] your answer, pasting all text into your answer with [correct formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Thx! This config works for me after delete "query_cache_size=0"
query_cache_size was removed in MySQL 8.
(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html)

Answer (score 1):

A lot of these tags can be used as commands in your docker-compose or Dockerfile actually.

Use `docker run -it --rm mysql:8 --verbose --help` to get all available commands for mysql 8 for example. For me, `--skip-performance-schema` and `--skip-mysqlx` were sufficient to cut mem usage by 2/3!

Answer (score 0):

You can try and appropriately reduce footage.

https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl